# Не находит класс SoapClient в PHP 5.4

Tags: php, soap

Доброе утро.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Установил себе php 5.4, попытался выполнить `$client = new SoapClient (....`

И получил фатальную ошибку об отсутствии класса :( Самое интересное - php-soap установлен.
Попробовал через pear установить - кричит, что есть.
Вопрос: где подводный камень плавает ?:)

Comment: А можно текст ошибки пхп копи пастом?

Answer (score 1):

В php.ini раскомментируйте строку:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

по умолчанию она закомментирована.

Comment: А с чего вы решили что у него версия под windows ? Просто праздный интерес :)

Comment: @shurik ну это самый очевидный вариант, для линуксоидов свойственно копать проблему до полного просветления. а на винде такой момент был в реале некоторое время назад.  
допускаю, что ошибка могла быть и на макоси и на солярисе до кучи...